# Getting javascript ES modules to work in NodeJS app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-modules

I have an app.js file built using NodeJS and ExpressJS, which calls a routes.js file for URL handling, and that in turn references a controller.js file which renders my templates/views.  I had multiple routes working with CommonJS, but when I tried to convert it all to ES Modules, I'm having problems.

The following code works with a route file with a single route.  But, I can't get it to work with more than one route.  It wants an `export default` for the single route, which does work, or gives me this error if I try multiple routes in a single route.js file: `Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`.  Maybe my syntax is off, maybe it's something else.

This is my working code, but it breaks when I try to add multiple routes...

Here's my app.js call to the routes file:

```
import shopRoutes from './routes/shop.js';
app.use(shopRoutes);
```

I'm calling the controller file from the routes file as such:

```
import express from 'express';
import * as shopController from '../controllers/shop.js';
const router = express.Router();
const shopIndex = router.get('/', shopController.getIndex);
// need to be able to use more routes like this, etc
// const shopIndex = router.get('/product', shopController.getProducts);
export default shopIndex;
```

And here's the related controller file:

```
export const getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('shop/index', {
    pageTitle: 'Shop',
    path: '/',
  });
};
// need to be able to use more functions for template assignment
// export const getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
//  res.render('shop/product', {
//    pageTitle: 'Product',
//    path: '/product',
//  });
// };

export default getIndex;
```

How can I have more than one route in the routes file, which would call multiple controller functions, using ES6 Modules?  Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: This should work just fine. Have you done any debugging (e.g. `console.log(shopController)` or inspecting variables at a breakpoint) to see what exactly is happening when it breaks?

Comment: `export default getIndex;` should not be necessary, you're using `shopController.getIndex` not `shopController.default`.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show that code that _isn't_ working? Commented-out code does nothing so it's difficult to tell what is and is not a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the default export from your *controller file*. You're already exporting `getIndex` as a named export and it doesn't really make sense to duplicate it as the default.

Then, add whatever route handlers you want to your *shop router* and export it

```js
// controllers/shop.js

export const getIndex = (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
};

export const getProducts = (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
};
```

```js
// routes/shop.js

import express from 'express';
import * as shopController from '../controllers/shop';

const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', shopController.getIndex);
router.get('/product', shopController.getProducts);

export default router;
```

```js
// app.js

import shopRouter from './routes/shop';

app.use(shopRouter);
```

---

I'm not a big fan of `*` imports and prefer being explicit...

```js
import { getIndex, getProducts } from '../controllers/shop';
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the commented-out code that the OP had tried? (Though I agree that this is the way to go and it should work)

Comment: @Bergi I know the router `.get()`, `.post()`, etc return the router but OP also seemed to be trying to re-declare the `shopIndex` const. I was mainly trying to make it clear that you can add to and export the router

Comment: Ah, I've missed that! (But that mistake wouldn't lead to the error they claim to be getting)

Comment: Thank you so much!  It works now.  I wasn't sure if someone would be able to debug with just the snippets I provided, but I thought that might be enough since it was likely a "typo" related to not fully understanding routers etc. (Yes, the second shopIndex in the routes file comment was just a typo as I created this post.)  The problem was pretty much my routes file.  When I was trying multiple paths, I was doing "export const shopIndex = router.get..." without the default export, when I should have done just "router.get" for each and exported the entire router as "export default router".

Comment: Oh, and your preference about being explicit with destructuring assignment in the import is duly noted.  If I only end up with a few named functions in the controllers file, I will do that in the routes file.

Comment: @david Oh don't mind, I do prefer the namespace imports for this - so choose your own :)